# Create [illinois-nlp] and [lbjava] tags

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, tag-creation-request

We are a research group at University of Illinois and have several tools available for NLP tasks. We get a good amount of traffic on our mailing list, and we would like to expand to Stack Overflow because the experience is so much better.

We would like to direct users to SO, but we have a chicken and egg problem - users can't get help on SO because the tags aren't there, and users won't go to SO for help if there are no tags. No one in the group has the requisite reputation to create tags.

Our request is that these tags are added:

- [illinois-nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/illinois-nlp)
- [lbjava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lbjava)

Comment: Are there questions on the site that require those tags? Tags are not created in the absence of content. If you have questions, list a couple and the community can have a look at what needs to be created.

Comment: There are not currently questions, but we have several questions waiting so they can use the tags. Perhaps the right thing is to post the questions first, and the tags will follow?

Comment: I've expanded upon my comment with the answer below. I think that's reasonable advice, but I'm sure others will provide their input as well.

Comment: I gave your question a slightly more generic title, because this is bound to come up again as a general issue.

Comment: What is `lbjava`? That might be allowable if it's a tool you're using or developing. A tag for your specific group (`illinois-nlp`) would be a meta tag though, so it would be edited out of any questions where it was added.

Comment: lbjava is a tool that are both using and developing. See: http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/page/software_view/LBJ

Comment: Your tag would be similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stanford-nlp ? And why can't you use the generic [tag:nlp]?

Comment: That is correct. We were impressed with the way they used Stack Overflow to help users. We can use the nlp tag, but it is much too general - especially in the cases where there is a problem with the software, not the technique.

Comment: @BilltheLizard if illinois-nlp would cover a specific suite of tools (as it seems to do for Stanford) that would be more acceptable, wouldn't it? Or would you just say "make tags for the individual ones"?

Comment: Your software is open for everyone, correct? Not only for students or researcher that work for you?

Comment: @Bart Oh yeah, that would be. I made the assumption that the tag was just for a group working out of the University of Illinois, which might be wrong.

Comment: @rene Right, it's open for everyone to use (subject to certain licensing conditions, but no more than your average free software).

Comment: @BillTheLizard The idea would be for the illinois-nlp tag to refer to the software suite in general. We have several tools, and it wouldn't make sense to have a tag for each of them.

Comment: Ok, I definitely had the wrong idea about that one. Since [stanford-nlp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stanford-nlp) already sets a precedent, and it seems like you're familiar with what kinds of questions get a good reception under that tag, I'd say you should be able to start posting questions for your tags.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Tags are not created in a void. Tags are created by adding them to questions that need those tags. And ideally this should not be just a single question. We have some very diligent members in our community who will clean up tags that don't seem to add value. So the process would be the following:

- Inform your users that they can ask questions on Stack Overflow and that some of you will keep an eye out for them. Please do point them to the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) when they are unfamiliar with Stack Overflow. What is a suitable question for your mailing list might not be suitable for Stack Overflow. And you don't want to end up with a bunch of disappointed users because their questions got downvoted or closed. (It might even be wise not to abandon your mailing list, should you be thinking of doing so)
- When you see that one or more questions have been asked, if a member of your community has sufficient reputation, they can add a tag themselves. If that doesn't happen, list the particular questions on Meta and a member of the community can add a tag.
- Once a tag has been created, fill out the tag wiki and tag wiki excerpt with information about the tag, [following our guidelines](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/). This helps where it comes to the community deciding whether or not the tag should stay.

If you are inclined to make up question and answer pairs just to get some content started, please don't. In my experience seeding your tag with such content is often not appreciated if the content isn't particularly good or seems contrived just to get tags going. Make sure you ask actual questions about actual problems you're facing. But that's just a word of personal advice.

Comment: Thanks. Point taken about seeding the content. As we use the software within the group, we often run into questions which could be of public interest, and these would be the candidates for going on Stack Overflow.

Comment: If they are "good content" in line with the scope of the site, you could self-answer a couple of them. But perhaps wait a bit before you do so. (And really make sure they're good). I've seen other projects do so to get their participation started, and the welcome was less than ideal with their questions being closed, deleted and tags removed.

Comment: For what it's worth [here is a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028657/semantic-role-labeler-used-in-java-vb-net) from outside the group.

Comment: Is there any chance you can edit that into a decent question @IllinoisNLP. It's not the kind of question that makes me want to start a tag.

Comment: Agreed, and edited. In all honesty, it's not a great question. That said, in the spirit of discussions like [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253473/should-we-add-rtfm-to-the-list-of-off-topic-close-reasons), we will still answer.

Comment: You'd like that to have the [illinois-nlp] tag?

Comment: "When you see that one or more questions have been asked," -- how can we tell that if a tag hasn't been created yet for the topic? There's nothing for us to subscribe to to be notified of questions in that topic. Seems to be a chicken or the egg situation. I shouldn't have to come to SO every day and search for the topic just to see if there are any posts related to it, I should be able to subscribe to the tag meant for it. But I can't do that until someone posts using the tag, which I wouldn't know about unless I come to SO every day to search for posts related to the topic.