# Should we add RTFM to the list of off-topic close reasons?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, scope, close-reasons, custom-close-reasons

If the answer to a question is patently in the official, easy to find, obvious documentation, 
the question has little value because:

- it is a basic question that 99% of visitors would already know
- the answer is already published
- any answer given would not stay as current as official documentation

So it should be closed, but the existing close reasons don't cover it. The most reasonable close reason would be a custom "...because the answer is available in official on-line documentation".

However this situation happens more often (in my experience) than some of the other pre-canned reasons.

What about adding a "the answer is available in official on-line documentation" to the menu?

Yes, I know it's already cluttered. I'd vote for removing some of the "other site" shortcuts and move them into the "other site" menu (one more click, big deal), leaving the front off-topic menu for custom reasons.

---

The close vote would require a link to said documentation. Like duplicates, 4 other people would need to agree to the link for the question to be closed. The post would be decorated with something like:

> This question has already has an answer in online documentation here: http://example.com/docs/bar.html

Comment: Read the _fantastic_ manual, you mean?  It'd be a great idea but I doubt if people would use it.  (Most would prefer to _answer_ anyways.)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason

Comment: A close vote is too generous, just downvote. "This question does not show any research effort."

Comment: @devnull I think **everybody** would use it. For everything seemingly trivial. "That's probably online somewhere. Go away".

Comment: @Bart: ...which is the whole point. It would be fantastic.

Comment: If you're an absolute ass without any regard for how bad an experience that is for the OP involved and how rude that is for the outside observer @Denis, sure, fantastic. And of course it does nothing to add any information to SO either. So yeah, great. /sarcasm.

Comment: My "answer" is the linked feature-request: RTFM *and also provide the reference link*. This is only from flagger POV though. I don't know how reviewer will feel; having to open the link and ensure that it's correct, might be another issue.

Comment: @Bart: SO is not a place where beginners should come to learn how to code by being spoonfed bits and pieces of docs.

Comment: @Denis which does however not imply that "oh, just go away" is the correct response.

Comment: @Bart and why should anybody care about being "rude" to someone who couldn't even bother to search before asking a (mostly low-quality) question here? Especially when "rude" means pointing them to existing material that covers their question? As Andrew said, a requirement to include a documentation link would be a very good idea. Sadly the close reason was dismissed after only being tested on the SciFi and English SE sites... which is stupid as both of these don't have many hard references and don't suffer from a huge stream of crap that requires such a close reason in the first place.

Comment: @Bart How often have you seen _basic_/_trivial_ questions being closed?  I see answers to those everyday even from those who have answered the same question scores of times.  It seems that we want to duplicate the _reference_ several times.

Comment: You don't end up just being rude to the OP @l4mpi. That's not the only person you're interacting with. You're also painting a picture for the wider audience. An atmosphere of "just go away" is negative and poisonous. You might get some pats on the back from your fellow curmudgeons and pride yourself in "keeping the site clean" and somehow "sticking it to the idiots", but it's an overall negative image. You can provide similar information in a far more informative, and positive or neutral manner. Andrew's idea, I agree, is far better. As is the link provided by BoltClock.

Comment: @devnull That "we" is then the community. They are the ones answering it. If you have a problem with that, organize yourselves to get the canonical duplicate and close against that. If you don't have the adequate means to do so, by all means let's find a way to make that easier.

Comment: @Bart you still fail to show how exactly this would be rude. If the close reason literally said `wtf n00b, RTFM`, that would be rude. But how is something like `This is covered in the official docs [here]` rude?

Comment: That [here] is not what this proposal states @l4mpi. Add it, and I'm far happier.

Comment: @Bart Nobody wants to close questions that might have been answered [hundreds of times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453482/python-projecteuler-q-5).  If this is the reaction to RTFM questions, then I shouldn't be complaining about those not being closed as duplicates.

Comment: *"Nobody wants to close questions that might have been answered hundreds of times."* ... what? @devnull

Comment: There was a hyperlink in there @Bart

Comment: @AndrewT. Agreed - see edit. Feel free to augment/alter edit.

Comment: There's lots of documentation that requires explanation. So this would have to be used with extreme care. And I don't think users can, in general, be trusted to do so.

Comment: I don't know where you draw the line on this.  [link to builtin function in python docs] is an obvious use-case for the "RTFM, go away" button, but how far do you go?  [link to Java Language Specification] is the answer to a lot of `java` tag questions but I think there's a good number of those that constitute good on-topic questions.

Comment: @roippi I think if the question is so straightforward that the doc *alone* explains it and you couldn't add much explanation then it's RTFM. If the doc is covering something that doesn't actually answer the question, isn't explained well or that could benefit from some explanation, then it is OK to answer here (probably with a reference to the doc of course)

Comment: I agree with @roippi: the JLS is extremely useful documentation and I'm sure a lot of highly voted questions get answered from this. But they are "TFM", so to speak. So what is included here: JLS, JavaDocs or both? Or in webdev: W3C (yes, I know) or MDN? Do we provide a checklist of resources people have to comb through first? 

If it is already explained in the docs, answer it once (CW answer?) by quoting the docs and closing subsequent questions like that as a duplicate.

Comment: This was already [tried once before and rejected](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason).

Comment: The links to the docs as suggested would be subject to link rot. As much as i'd love to be able to close the RTFM questions, there really isn't an elegant way to do it other than as a duplicate.

Comment: @KevinB if the definition if link rot is they be one broken, surely a periodic automated check of all such links could be carried out to ensure they aren't 404. And if only "official" links are acceptable (ie no blogs or other 2nd class sites), then non 404 should be enough to validate them.

Comment: "Are downvotes and closevotes the same thing?" No.

Comment: One thing I will say is that when I have a question about the documentation, the first thing I do is Google it. And as frequently as not, some inexperienced programmer asked that question on StackOverflow a few years ago and received a still-relevant answer. Usually, these answers are good enough that I can skip going to the official documentation altogether, saving me quite a bit of time.

Comment: How would it differ from 'too broad' except being a 'hyphen-word'? There are enough close reasons people don't fully understand or find it hard to differ, for example 'unclear what you're asking' and 'no sufficient information to diagnose'

Comment: I agree this would not fly because of the link reason.  But wait ... what if all links given for the close due to RTFM had to be Google links since Google knows it all?

Comment: FYI I just stumbled on to this [case in point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345215/difference-between-nsarray-and-nsmutablearray) (see comment #2)

Comment: Note that sometimes the _best_ documentation is not easily found, and you can only search for it if you know the right search terms which you don't when you haven't read the documentation yet.

Comment: What if the documentation is/goes missing? What if it's out of date? What if it's wrong? What if the documentation is insufficiently clear? What if the documentation is incomplete or if there is no canonical documentation? What if the documentation requires some sort of authentication that you have and other people don't? What if the documentation requires some deep understanding that you have and the user in question does not (like crypto, graphics, or networking)? You *cannot* assume that just because you understand and can find the documentation, everyone else can too.

Comment: I've gotten a RTFM comment in an answer...and the linked reference was to documentation in a different programming language. The people answering / commenting thought it was sufficient, but it didn't help me AT ALL. People new to programming, or to a specific language, aren't necessarily equipped to understand the manual and might need a little bit more help.

Comment: I wrote a little bit about this [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167767/204137) - the manuals aren't always the best way to learn things.

Comment: If I Google a problem and get links to the manual and Stack Overflow on the results page, I usually go to SO. The Q & A format and typical accompanying discussion is usually a much better learning resource, and in general you can't get that anywhere else. IMHO, if we compromise SO's ability to provide that resource, we compromise both SO's visibility and its utility.

Comment: @BobSammers I'm not talking about most of the questions where some discussion is warranted or necessary. I'm talking about the simple questions where the asker needed only to read the documentation to find the answer, and where discussion is not only unnecessary but noise. These answers add no real value.

Comment: @Bohemian - I should have acknowledged you're only talking about pretty basic questions. That said, I worry a) about further intimidation of newbies and b) about the subjective identification of what is 'basic' and what is not. WRT the noise (and my point, really): I honestly think that balance is about right where it is - I don't see a lot of noise in day to day use and with overzealous implementation of such a rule (tempting to some, I've no doubt), we risk the problems I mentioned originally. Personally, I think duplication within SO is a much bigger problem.

Comment: RTFM is an asshole answer.  This is not an asshole site.

Comment: @BaileyS Everyone should read the FAQ & manual before being able to use the software. It's more educational than a EULA.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman Question closed as, 'Unlicensed', user did not read EULA!

Comment: Just to play devil's advocate: this site has kind of become TFM. Try googling for nearly any specific problem and look who appears near the top…

Comment: Related: [What happened to the “You're Just Lazy” close vote reason?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216491/what-happened-to-the-youre-just-lazy-close-vote-reason)

Comment: I'd definitely like to see this, but it's unlikely, given how close codes have been "dumbed down".

Comment: I would absolutely support this. I've always maintained that it's not the job of Stack Overflow to mirror all the world's documentation in Q&A format.

Comment: i just came across [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341393/how-do-i-create-a-simple-javascript-program-that-displays-the-value-of-input-ty). The OP  says that he knows the logic but don't know the syntax. After each problem being solved, he keeps own coming up with new queries. What he needs to do is actually read some tutorials. Yes, We need RTFM, or at least something more specific than too broad, like **go read some tutorials** :/

Comment: if only there were a stackoverflow manual explaining this, so that the answer would be RTFM...

Comment: Here's a classic, archetypical example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100609/how-does-set-decides-uniqueness-of-values-being-added-in-set

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CROSS SITE META DUPLICATE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason)

Answer (score 186):

While you may have seen hundreds (or thousands) of questions that fit this category (and I feel your pain about it), there are a few reasons why we *shouldn't* have that close reason:

- we have a policy against [LMGTFY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM#List_of_similar_initialisms) links either as comments or answers. The reasons you've specified for having an RTFM reason are very similar or the same to the reasons why people left LMGTFY links.
- it might be a basic question, but that in itself is no reason to prevent having it asked and answered on Stack Overflow. Subsequent questions about the same thing should be duplicate linked to the original question/answer.
- frequently the basic question could be asked and answered in a way that isn't represented in the official online documentation. For example, we still see questions asking the difference between pre and post incrementation—one of the more basic topics—but people are still confused about it despite the numerous articles out there.
- an RTFM close reason will be used as the lazy person's close reason (much like the old *not constructive* close reason was) when in fact the question can be answered and/or duplicate linked.

## Edit

A couple of new angles on this have occurred to me and they should be noted here as well. (Keep in mind that at no stage am I advocating that we allow lazy or junk questions—these are well discussed in the past. This is purely about "RTFM" as a close reason.)

Remember all the recent moderator candidates who promised to *"help the newbies because we're too harsh on them"*? They were making that promise because there is a perceived problem, and users are already finding the bar to active participation quite high. Introducing an RTFM close reason will help undo any progress in that area.

**Do you doubt what I'm saying?** Take a trip back to [Usenet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet) days, where *"RTFM you n00b!"* was the standard answer for any new user. That made Usenet a scary and challenging place for newbies; you had to have massive persistence to be able to stick around and eventually earn the right to issue the statement to newbies yourself.

If the RTFM close reason was introduced here, who is going to police it? Who is going to make sure that it isn't getting out of control? Who is going to answer all the Meta questions from discouraged users who had a question closed for it? Who is going to check the target documentation and make sure it is clear enough and of sufficient quality that every newbie (of any culture, including non-English speaking) should be able to understand it?

**Question:** what is the difference between a newbie asking a question that's covered by the documentation and an experienced user asking a more technical question that is also covered by the documentation?

**Answer:** *there is absolutely no difference.* Yet, we have no issues with creating a good answer for those experienced users' questions, pointing them to the relevant documentation as a reference, and then filling in the gaps for them. Why can't we do the same for newbies?

Comment: In a more recent example, RTFM would replace the "minimal understanding" close reason too.

Comment: "but people are still confused about it despite the numerous articles out there" **because they cannot be bothered to locate or read them**. FTFY.

Comment: +1 for your last point: the "RTFM" close reason will be abused for **any** question which is remotely "easy"

Comment: @Matt: And what? They'll then get closed as they should be.

Comment: @Denis: which is where we disagree. An answer becomes "easy"/"simple" **once you've solved the problem yourself**. To the beginner though, it's still a hard problem to solve. "RTFM" will end up being used as close reasons for questions which, whilst not complex, are **not** *actually* in the documentation. Show your hatred for these questions by downvoting and moving on, not by VtC.

Comment: @Matt: for a coder, even a beginner, a simple google or doc away from getting fixed should not be classed as a "hard" problem

Comment: A (suitable) LMGTFY link is actually a better answer than many answers I see, as it "teaches a man to fish". Bohemian's proposal now includes the requirement to link to the original documentation: on that basis it gets parity with SO's existing "duplicate of..." close reason, and would serve over time to improve the standard of questions which those users would be likely to leave in future.

Comment: Let's not forget all the manuals that are opaque or downright wrong.

Comment: @ClickRick There is nothing stopping people from leaving a link to the doco now. If you've ever spent time in newsgroups you would have seen the hurdle that RTFM answers produce - they can downright alienate new users.

Comment: Oh, I spent plenty of time on BBSs and Usenet, on a range of topics. Properly resourced RTFM answers were the least of their troubles.

Comment: I think I should mention that some easy questions covered by documentation can be hard to search for. Pre-incrementation/post-incrementation is a good example of that—if you only know the `++` symbol, and not the words that relate to its use in C relatives, you may find it rather hard to find what you seek.

Comment: One issue I have is an RTFM answer is effectively plagiarism of the official doc, so our attribution standards require a link... to the doc. And thrre's the rub. And further we are not adding value with such an answer - we are just a cache of the doc. Answers requiring explanation of doc (eg some subtle point) I am fine with, because we're adding value.

Comment: @Slugster I think you nailed it.  Other than that there's just that big huge difference between the way the world ought to be and the way it is.

Comment: I keep hearing that the bar to entry is too high, but I also see lots of questions that show little to no attempt at research. There have literally been questions where the _exact_ text of the question yields the correct answer in google, as the first hit. So however high the bar to participation is at SO, it is apparently comparable with googling. That strikes me as too low, not too high.

Comment: My least favorite LMGTFY answers are the ones that are the first result on Google for the question I've searched for.

Comment: Can we just have an angry face button that shows the question as closed just for the person who clicked it and for everyone else just shows up as downvote.

Comment: That's exemplary answer that address *imaginary* Stack Overflow site.

Comment: @Cupcake You have a point, but I think it is a different one. I think the industry is going to strike trouble in a few years when 100% of the participants were educated after SO came into being and answers were a couple of keystrokes away - none of them will have a clue how to solve the truly tricky problems.

Comment: well said, it will become the standard reason to close anything that people don't consider interesting enough to look up an answer for... And with the internet now, good chance some blog or other website has something that could help figure out an answer to most things, so anything at all would fall under it.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/

Comment: Also a "google away" implies someone has enough experience to know what the terminology is for somthing.  In C# the `?` operator has a couple different terms associated with it depending on the usage.  If you come across it in code, it's nearly impossible to google if you've never seen it before.  The ternary operator is covered in many texts, but the nullability operator is often not covered in basic texts.

Comment: @AaronLS I try to be friendly to people who ask ultra-newb questions if it's one of those "don't know what to look for until you know the answer" situations, like the ternary operator. In fact, I called out someone for being rude in one of those situations. But just yesterday I saw [yet another example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23615682) where googling the _exact_ text of the subject line gave the results. That's not being a newb to programming, or even a newb to SO; that's just plain laziness. You don't need to be an "insider" to know that's disrespectful of other people's time.

Comment: And I do think SO needs to take care of its "old" members as well as being welcoming to new ones. I used to answer a lot of questions; now I spend _much_ less time at the site, because the signal-to-noise ratio is so low that it's not worth it -- it's not _fun_ anymore. I'm helping fewer people, and it looks like [I'm not the only one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252756). A few bad questions here and there are something we can all handle; an influx of them hurts the whole site, and that's what we seem to have now.

Comment: _"and then filling in the gaps for them. Why can't we do the same for newbies?"_ - It's the "filling in the gaps" part that makes your hypothetical experienced user's question valid. If the relevant documentation doesn't explain something well that can confuse even experienced users. On the other hand when a newbie posts a "What does the jQuery `.toggle()` method do?" question, the best answer really is "RTFM and come back with a more detailed question if you still don't understand."

Comment: *close reason will be used as the lazy man's close reason* The lazy man already uses the existing close reasons as a close reason. Adding another one won't change this at all.

Comment: " there is absolutely no difference. Yet we have no issues with creating a good answer for those experienced user's questions, pointing them to the relevant documentation as a reference, and then filling in the gaps for them." Meh. The experienced user is first off better at asking questions *generally* (explaining concepts using jargon properly; writing clearly about concepts due to having a clearer mental model, etc.). Despite that, I *absolutely will* get upset with experienced users who ask questions that are *directly* answered by the documentation, and that *does frequently happen*.

Comment: On the flip side, I have all kinds of sympathy for a beginner who can't put together two concepts from the documentation in order to solve a problem, or struggles with even a simple "reverse documentation" problem - the documentation answers "what does X do?", but the question is "which thing does Y?", and sometimes there are a **lot** of candidate "things". In short, it is 100% about the "filling in the gaps" part, and about *what those gaps consist of, and whether they are in fact there at all*.

Comment: The acid test: would a link-only answer to the question (where it is obvious what link to use), actually answer the question? Then it is not a good question, as it naturally attracts answers that should be flagged and deleted.

Answer (score 74):

One aspect not considered by the question or other answers is, the mere existence of an official manual or canonical answer does not mean that everyone looking at it would be able to comprehend and use it in its current form. Official documentation can often be overwhelming to me as a newbie, I simply do not know where to start or what to look for. It might assume prior knowledge or other context that I may not have.

Therefore, there is a lot of value in answers which not only link to the doc, but pinpoint the correct location, as well as clarify assumptions and expand on the (often terse) prose of the doc.

Comment: I agree to some extent with that.  Oh look, I just found that in an Advanced Javascript book ... it must be RTFM!

Comment: This. `man rsync` without ever having typed `rsync` can be completely overwhelming. Searching for tutorials can help but I think a lot of us forget that we at one point learned the sort of thing (incantations) to type into Google in the first place in order to get decent results. If you don't understand that you have a syntax error in a JavaScript line Googling 'foo is not an object' (the error the browser gave you) is pretty much useless.

Comment: You're right; technical documentation is often aimed at experts, not n00bs. Even being an expert in one field may not help you in a similar field. Being a SQL Server expert doesn't buy you much in trying to understand Oracle; a C expert won't understand basic C++ jargon.

Comment: I'm always nervous about "everyone looking at it would be able to comprehend and use it". If official documentation, dozens or hundreds of previously existing answers, uncountably many links around the internet and who knows how many books, etc., already exist, what makes us think that adding another new answer will make a difference? It's necessary to review what already exists in order to guess what alternative phrasing might make a difference for each new question.

Comment: yes, the prototypical usenet question of yesteryear would be "how do I use man", with the prototypical 'answer' of "RTFM" (meaning there, read the f'in man page, iow issue man man). An answer so utterly useless and insulting it's worse than the question.

Comment: True... But then you have questions like [Is there a “not equal” operator in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11060506/156755)

Comment: @Basic but that isn't *merely* answered by reading the documentation, it's answered by typing `python not equal` into any search engine and blindly clicking on anything that comes up on the first page or so. (I feel bad for the herpetologists out there.) It's different when the documentation is authoritative and you have to parse documentation-speak *and search* the documentation for something that looks like it does what you want, without knowing what it's called.

Answer (score 41):

### No.

This is effectively the "link-only answer" version of Close as Duplicate. Just as hard to use as the latter, but with more randomly-broken links in harder-to-edit places.

The solution to the underlying problem is to make close-as-duplicate faster and easier to use - then encourage folks to beef up the answers being pointed to rather than re-answering the same damn questions every day.

Which is a hard enough problem all on its own.

#### See also:

- [If General Reference becomes a close reason, add a field for an url like for duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80190/if-general-reference-becomes-a-close-reason-add-a-field-for-an-url-like-for-dup)
- [General Reference questions create low-quality dead ends for Googlers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160565/general-reference-questions-create-low-quality-dead-ends-for-googlers)
- [Introduce a  "general reference" close reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason/88521#88521)
- [Create CW answer for every "Vote to close as duplicate" vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198958/create-cw-answer-for-every-vote-to-close-as-duplicate-vote)

Comment: Amen! This really IS a "General Reference" close reason; renamed... and as a regular user on a site where G.R. close reason was tried and failed miserably, I can fully confirm that it's a Bad Idea.

Comment: Broken links are no worse than outdated answers (IMO they are better, at least with a broken link you know the truth is outta here). Yes, RTFM flag can and will be misused, but so is duplicate flag, so should it be removed as well? I hope not.

Answer (score 23):

We had such a close reason. It was something along the line of "the user must demonstrate a minimal understanding about the topic discussed". Which is more politically correct... since the true meaning of the F in RTFM is not "friendly", but rather the F word.

This was a good close reason which was most suitable for a lot of crap questions. Particularly code begging. Whatever you might think of the "minimal understanding" close reason, the true story is all the crap questions that sort under that category are still closed today.

Sometimes they are closed as duplicates, but more often they are closed as something that doesn't make any sense, such as "unclear what you are asking" or "the question lacks details". Since "minimal understanding" was removed as close reason, I've also seen an increase in weird, custom-made close reasons like "no research", "the user lacks knowledge" etc. They are often on the border to rude.

I think that bringing back the "minimal understanding" close reason would solve a lot of problems. I never understood why it was removed in the first place. This is not a site for homework questions nor is it a beginner programming tutorial site.

---

**EDIT**

I just found the minimal understanding close reason again! We were just silly, it was never gone, just hidden. On the holiest of SO pages, ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), we can read:

> 3.Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they
>   didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow
>   question checklist.

Everyone *shall* follow the SO main policy page. Therefore we should close all such posts. This is how you do it:

- Click "close" for the off-topic question meeting the criteria.
- Click "off-topic because...".
- Click "Other".
- Paste the below text:

> The question appears to be off-topic, because questions asking for
>   code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being
>   solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the
>   expected results. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

It would be better if there was a pre-made close reason for this, but until there is, we can use the above method.

Comment: Bring. Back. The. RTFM. Close. Reason. Now.

Comment: @Isaac It was never gone, apparently. See edit above.

Comment: That particular reason was *intended* to be used for "give me a fish" questions - or "code begging", as you named it. *"Here's a list of requirements <no question follows>"* / *"here's my assignment <that's a very nice assignment, did you wish for us to admire it?>"* / etc. It was removed because folks were using it for any and all questions they considered "too basic", in some cases going back and closing [canonical questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/) because they didn't include a code dump. That was... counter-productive.

Comment: @Shog9 People used it for those reasons because such questions aren't desired by the community. SO is not a beginner tutorial. Removing the close option changed nothing, you'll still see these very same questions closed today, just with very strange close reasons, when no duplicate was easily found.

Comment: This is what makes writing specific descriptions for close reasons so tricky, @Lundin: ideally, we want to capture the intent of the folks closing, but there's always the side-effect of folks misunderstanding the description and thinking an entirely new class of questions has suddenly become disallowed. Note that "beginner" is relative; I've watched many experienced C++ programmers brought low when faced with a new API; heck, even finding the relevant documentation in MSDN can be a challenge, interpreting it properly is a minefield.

Comment: @Lundin it's gone now...

Comment: @CalvT We're nowadays aiming for a site where those with minimum knowledge of the topic learn, share and make their homework.

Answer (score 19):

Disagree for now.  But I'll reverse my position and support it the day the documentation for all websites on the Internet are:

- community editable
- kept up to date
- don't break links for the sake of laziness and/or whimsy

The "official" documentation for APIs and software appears to be done by people who care less about their high-traffic URIs than I do about a link visited by perhaps five people a year.  They have no adherence to ["cool URIs don't change"](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html).

For instance: the Qt library has what most think to be exemplary documentation.  Yet breaking link after link with each time it's passed on.  `trolltech.com` croaks, then it's at `nokia.com` for a while, then it's at `qtproject.org` and echoed at `digia.com` here and there.

*(Apparently no one was willing to pay for and negotiate the $12/yr and $5/mo for a redirecting server as the hot potato jump'd about...)*

That's an example from people whose link structure is pretty sane and easy, and are mostly known for making good documentation.  Compare it to MSDN or other insanity, where the URL looks like a Google Map link or Amazon product profile.  For all we know those numbers contain some kind of viral code--not that most people feel like analyzing it.  :-/  But I think it's enough to say the links suck and they break.

So if someone asks an unanswerable question, put it "on hold" it because it's not clear or good.  If it's a duplicate question, put it "on hold" because it's a duplicate.

BUT if it's answerable and no one has asked it yet, let it be.  Ideally probe to flesh it out so the person asking gives it more dimensionality; which might help bring it up in more relevant searches.  Then give good, sage answers, and close future duplicates of that question that offer no new nuances.

Be better than the documentation, and outlive it--which isn't hard.  *Because given current practices on the Interweb: being better than the documentation is doing battle with an unarmed opponent*.

Comment: Just for reference, not all language documentation (Java and Python, especially) have fairly stable documentation access by URL and thus RTFM closure may be appropriate for those tags.

Comment: Basic Java and iOS/Objective-C documentation is quite stable.  Just because some documentation is hard to find does not mean that a poster is absolved from the responsibility to TRY to find something.

Comment: @HotLicks If you are not inclined, don't answer.  Downvote if you think the question sucks.  But when the M in RTFM that you really mean GTFM *(Google-the-freaking-manual)* is dependent on G and M then I think it's a lousy close reason.  I don't trust G or M, or when you come down to it SE either, but that's why redundancy is good.  And at least here there's some hope for improvement over time.

Answer (score 6):

However desirable this would be to keep this site clean, the sorry truth is that junk is very welcome on it.

Over the years, we've banned LMGTFY links and removed all of the potential close reasons that even remotely suggested OPs to get lost and help themselves before asking.

The reasoning behind this is adequately expressed by @slugster: "it might be a basic question, but that in itself is no reason to prevent having it asked and answered on StackOverflow".

Translation: Junk welcome; traffic is king.

This isn't something everyone agrees with, but that's the way it is.

The only option we've left when we don't is to downvote, and I do not imagine this will change.

Comment: Yes, that is it: _Junk welcome; traffic is king._  Noone would admit it, though.

Comment: You seem to be equating *basic* questions with *junk* questions. They are not the same and I never implied that they were, that translation is totally incorrect. There are already mechanisms to get rid of junk.

Comment: @slugster, the vast majority of basic questions have already been answered.  Sometimes very well, often early on in the site, often with lots of upvotes, often showing up in the list of possible dupes that you get when posting a question.  **Every basic question closed as a dupe *is* a junk question.**

Comment: I concur, just having traffic does not result in a good Q&A platform, see on Quora, they basically accept any junk you throw at it, does not enhance the experience at all, since the S/R ratio is reduced dramatically

Comment: @Charles: For *those* junk questions, we don't need a new rtfm close reason if they can be closed as duplicates. Slugster is referring to the (minority of) good, basic questions.

Comment: @Denis you seem to suffer from a common SO problem. "If everyone thought just like I do, this site would be so much cleaner". Communication is really hard. A lot harder than programming. Kudos to you for thoroughly combing through all the rules and culture of SO before participating. The truth is most people see a Q/A site and they think it reasonable to put their question there. So they post their question it gets downvoted and closed with no clear explanation. So what does this result in. They come back and try again not having learned anything from the previous attempt.

Comment: This answer is so true it hurts. Duplicates may be junk, but simple RTFM questions, like [syntax of a statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745559/mysql-if-else-statement-confusion) also fall in that category, I think.

Answer (score 6):

As someone who has encountered my fair share of `RTMF`ers I can attest that almost every question can be answered by reading the appropriate documentation. But often that documentation is cryptic, poorly organized, or commonly misunderstood. This alone is enough to think twice about adding this as a reason. But it seems that almost all questions already fall neatly into the existing categories. When a person asks a question either you can provide a succinct answer(in which case you answer it), the answer already exists on SO(which makes it a duplicate), or the question isn't appropriate for SO(it gets closed for one of the plethora of reasons in the close dialogue).

Comment: But very often it is not.  And the two most common questions for iOS/Objective-C programming are `[SomeClass someMethod] Unrecognized selector`, and "I tried to parse a date into NSDate and got a nil", both of which, if Googled will come up with hundreds of references.  Not suppressing these duplicates, in fact, makes Google less effective since one is more likely to hit one of the dupes that has, out of sheer fatigue, been allowed to languish without marking a dupe.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your concern. SO provides a close reason for "Duplicate"

Comment: But I don't think we should each have keep a set of bookmarks to all the common dupes.  The SO search is so poor that finding a "good" dupe (especially given all of yesterday's dupe-dupes) will likely take 5 minutes.  With roughly a dozen (that I read) of these low-quality, poorly-researched questions coming through daily, that's an hour of my time.  Very few people are going to spend that much time on this, so they just down-vote, or they select a close code at random.

Comment: If you can't find a good duplicate easily how do you expect the OP to?

Comment: One of the reasons why I can't find good examples is that I trip over all the stupid dupes.  And the onus *should* be on the OP to do more work than you or I would have to do to find the info.

Comment: Its tricky, my primary reason for speaking out against the RTFM I think it will be abused. Take for instance this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-last-git-commit. This problem is clearly documented in the reference material. Would 5 experts be wrong if they closed it? Disclosure, the first time I needed to undo a commit this is where I found my answer. Disclosure again, git's man pages are notoriously difficult to decipher.

Comment: Like any of the closing codes, an RTFM code could be abused.  If you exclude closing reasons that can be abused we would never close anything.  Git is particularly inscrutable, and the documentation is quite fragmented and poorly organized -- you can only really understand the documentation if you know Git well enough that you don't need it, so folks have a pretty valid excuse for asking for help.  Others, like the functions of Java's String, are easy to understand and readily accessible and "obvious" -- there's no real excuse for not consulting them.

Comment: I hear ya, but additionally its a philosophical problem. This is a question/answer site. Its stated goal is to '...build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming....'. This leads one to believe that it includes questions about programming covered in the documentation. A duplicate close vote is in line with this goal because it says "An answer to this already exists on SO" an RTFM is not because it says "An answer to this exists elsewhere". If you accept RTFM as a reason to close a question then you find yourself in direct conflict with the stated goal of the site.

Comment: Except that dupe and RTFM are basically saying the same thing -- the answer is available elsewhere (and likely a reasonable effort on the part of the OP would have found it).

Comment: If they are the same thing then there is no need for another option. So far all I have heard is that finding a duplicate is too much trouble. Thats exactly why the RTFM option shouldn't exist(see above treatments on the "lazy man's duplicate" option). Either its answered on SO or its not. If its not it should be left open and if it is you need to provide the duplicate. Its not good enough to say "its probably answered on SO somewhere"

Answer (score 5):

Another slightly off-topic answer:  Rather than closing codes and downvotes, what if there were an "automaton" that read questions (maybe just those from new posters or posters with low reps) and "gently guided" those that were clearly dupes or of poor quality.

Eg, it might say: *`unrecognized selector` is a common iOS exception and has many answers already.  Examine the list below, and if you do not find your answer you may post this question.*

(And then somehow require evidence that the poster at least skimmed through the references, eg.)

It would, of course, require some sort of natural language and AI "stuff" (which I'm not volunteering to write), and would not handle every situation.  But I suspect it could be made to work for a subset of the problem questions.

**Added:** And companion feature would be to allow people to somehow nominate and vote for the "best dupes" for common questions -- versions of the questions that were well-presented and which had suitably instructive and enlightening answers.  Or perhaps have some sort of "wiki" of "standard answers" for the common dupes.

Comment: I don't think this is possible from first principles. The (high quality) training set should specifically be about duplicates and even then it may not be possible.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a software developer that uses a couple different languages at once, so quite a bit of the time I'm just looking for a specific syntax of a statement. I know that X language should be able to do Y but how exactly to do it is up in the air. Yes, most languages have online documentation but it doesn't exactly follow any kind of convention. MSDN is different than Java docs which is different than Python. (Java docs are probably the best IMO.) Then there are version changes, etc. which further complicate the issue.

Using a search engine like Google in combination with online forums (mostly SO), I can get the answers quickly. When I am learning a new language or getting back into a language that I haven't used for a while this is the easiest way for me to do it and I can do it while I'm building whatever it is I'm working on.

Languages, frameworks and other tools are moving all the time so this knowledge is typically transient anyway. Yes, you should know the underlying concepts. Hopefully you've learned those already.

If you believe that holding all the syntax in your head of all the languages you are using right now is an essential skill of a programmer and anyone who can't do that should find a different vocation then these low level, basic questions have no place. Otherwise it is a handy, point to point reference tool that is easily accessible to outside search engines.

Comment: "I know that X language should be able to do Y but how exactly to do it is up in the air". Ok, but what did you _try_? If you didn't try anything, then your question isn't very good.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - I don't ask the questions. I benefit from some other person asking a 'stupid' question. Typically SO gives more pointed advice than the docs. In particular, the Python docs are adequate but they're unconventional and have all sorts of compatibility issues across versions. Also, something like Beautiful Soup is much easier to get answers on SO than from the documentation which is pretty sparse.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - I'm essentially saying 'RTFM' is not a valid response.  Just because it *is* documented *somewhere* doesn't mean it shouldn't be on SO as well. If it is a duplicate, point to the original question or just *ignore* it. The search tools are there to help filter the garbage.

Comment: RTFM "first" is a perfectly valid response. If one reads the manual and it is then not sufficient, then there is the basis of a question. What I dislike is questions where there are perfectly adequate docs that the OP either didn't know about, or didn't bother to read. In either of those cases, directing the OP to the documentation is appropriate. If the documentation in not adequate, then it is not appropriate to direct the OP to it.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with RTFM is that the solution to a particular problem may seem obvious to one by reading the doc, but not to another.

Example (not an actual example):

> How do I set text to a `TextView` in android

Answer:

> RTFM, `TextView.setText`

Seems trivial to anyone with a minimal background in android

A bit more complex

> Why doesn't my `db.rawQuery(TABLE, 'name = toto', null)` work

Is quite trivial to anyone who is familiar with SQL (`toto` would be considered a column, raising an explicit exception)

And so one. Anyone (almost) would agree to close the first as RTFM (although it should actually be marked as duplicate since there has to be a duplicate of this)

The problem is *Where do you draw the line between `trivial` and `easy for me, but not to the RTFM point`?*

Comment: Pretty much where you draw it, IMO. Can the question be answered in full by doing a trivial Google search? It's a RTFM question. Can it not? It's not.

Comment: A lot of trivial Google searches answer the question in full because one of the first results is the answer on SO.

Comment: @jwg What's your point?  Why does that have any effect on the process Pekka described?

Answer (score 4):

I generally agree to the whole “Read The Fine Manual…” concept, but for one thing: Most people *do not know that a manual even exists*. And you’d be shocked how many people using Unix/Linux-based systems—Mac OS X, Ubuntu, etc…—have *100% no clue that the [`man`](https://kb.iu.edu/data/afjm.html) command exists*.

When people look at my desk & see little to no books on the work I do they wonder where I get the info. I show them how to just type, `man grep` and their jaws drop.

The issue is—at least in the Unix/Linux world—that while the command line is where most of the work is done, few people truly realize what a rich learning tool they have right on their desktop.

Now RTFM back in 1991… Anyone doing this kind of work knew *exactly* what that meant then!

Comment: and most of the manuals are far from fine... I've seen a lot of "manuals" that were utterly wrong, impossibly indexed, and/or lacking even basic information. Yet it's "the manual" and there's a few lines in it no doubt that to a domain expert with 10 years experience working with the product brings back enough memories of the issue at hand that for him it contains the answer...

Comment: Any competent programmer should know that the first step to take when approaching an unfamiliar technology is to identify (and bookmark) the available documentation.  Yes, one may not find "the right stuff" immediately, and some stuff (more and more, sadly) is poorly documented at best, but there is a lot of pretty good documentation out there that folks never make an attempt to consult.  Of course, a big part of the problem is that SO is catering more and more to "programmers" who are not even marginally competent.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that something is covered in official documentation or general reference is not sufficient reason to close a question.  Some good points in support of this have already been brought up in other answers (e.g. the docs or "general reference" may not be as grokkable as an answer provided by SO; there may be subtle nuances that are better addressed by a custom answer on SO; RTFM-style responses are newbie-hostile; etc.).

What I haven't seen yet in the answers so far is that one of Stack Overflow's goals (I believe[1]) is to become the *de facto* canonical repository of programming knowledge.  In other words, *within SO's domain*, SO aims to ultimately encompass and supersede all other sources.  It doesn't do this by being "Link Central" but by having the actual content.  Sure, people are going to use Google, but the ambition is for the most relevant SO question to be the top hit in any given programming-related Google search.

[1]Credit/blame where it's due:  I didn't just come up with these ideas myself.  I could have sworn I read them in a blog or other meta post, perhaps by one of the SO founders.  If not a founder, then most likely some extremely well-respected user from SO or English Language & Usage.

Comment: That's a terrible goal, IMO. Stack Overflow shouldn't replace the world's manuals. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160565/general-reference-questions-create-low-quality-dead-ends-for-googlers

Comment: You are exactly right John Y, that was one of the explicit goals of the site and why simple questions are allowed.

Comment: If that is a goal, it seems to me that there should be a subsidiary goal to prevent/remove questions that have no value.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is clearly expressed in the documentation for Stack Overflow. Perhaps some wise one who doesn't like people asking questions could close it, in order to keep the site pure?

Comment: "The close vote would require a link to said documentation" Where's your link? (I'll add that this proposal, or something very like it, has been made before.)

Answer (score -1):

Generally you don't need entire page to answer a question. Why don't you provide a link in **answer** instead and quote a relevant excerpt from the documentation page?

Comment: Oleg - your foolish answer does not address the critical issue, **how to make more points for the points crowd**.  I guess you have a vote-me-down wish.

Answer (score -2):

**tl;dr**: No RTFM tag. Instead another (friendlier) tag or message which would tell about the duplicateness and provide some direction.

---

When you search for `RTFM` as a civilian, you will find `Read the f***g manual`, which is, as is, *unhelpful*, *arrogant*, ivory tower b.s. that is *hostile* and *ignorant* to every newcomer because to them it means "**Get off my lawn, this ground is for the elite only. F** you and go away, please.**".

And this is not even my own opinion, rather I got told this opinion a few months ago by an experienced and well-traveled electrical engineer in my family, who knows more about life and different culture than most of us (including you, you, you, and especially you as well as myself). He was looking for advice on a program he was trying to write, but found only arrogant, hostile and ignorant RTFM answers (and has not even posted himself). Since then, he understandably avoids OUR ELITIST A*HOLE COMMUNITY altogether.

*Everybody voting pro RTFM closing:* Thanks. It's your fault he sees us exactly like we are (I repeat myself, but): arrogant, ignorant, hostile. AIH!

You can answer every question on the world either with `RTFM`, `Ask your vendor` or the latter's younger brother `Look into the sourcecode` <strike>except those not solved by science, yet.</strike>. Even questions not solved by science can be solved by RTFM (it might only depend on relativity and quantum mechanics).

If you don't consider a question as RTFM-answerable, than it's because you are not elite enough, yet. In reality, it is f**ing RTFM-ible, you are just too low to realize the sprouts of the docs.

And, pre-finally: If you vote *for* a RTFM-closing, then you should better be immediately able to define where the boundaries between RTFM and non-RTFM questions are. Does it stop when a question cannot be solved with a verbatim snippet from the f**ing manual? Or where does it?

I am guilty myself, yet I'd like to advertise more humility in our community. Let's become a community other communities like, and let us respect the other communities. Let us become guides to them, and once upon a time they may become our guides.

Comment: To clarify: nobody is talking about actually using the literal phrase "RTFM". As to where the boundaries lie: if *Googling a question's title* leads to a *perfect* answer (like when my question is "how do I do {very simple thing}?" and first hit is a manual page saying `functionname() - does {very simple thing}`  then that to me is an RTFM question. There are way too many of those and they're a sign you didn't even do a simple Google search. If that is somehow elitist, then colour me so. (But - what you describe is the reason why this has never been implemented as a close reason)

Comment: @Pekka웃: Of course I am also exaggerating a little bit w.r.t. the language used. However, in times where google results differ for any person, even that boundary seems fragile. A newbie might have had a history of googling for C++, C# or for example other languages with funny characters in their name. Then someone might not even use google. For myself, I regularly fail to search for C++ jobs on certain job-sites, and find driving license C jobs instead. All in all, I discover that whenever I enter a new topic, I often fail on "RTFM-questions", and then would be thankful for real adivce ...

Comment: ... e.g. "You may want to use the search like this or that. For you, we have [this](url) answer."

Comment: If people aren't coming here to ask questions simply because they're unwilling/unable to run their question through google first, and such unresearched questions are not well received, then I consider that *a great thing*.  We don't *want* people who are only going to ask those types of questions.  We don't want people who are going to be *answering* those types of questions (because it encourages undesirable behavior).  SO is explicitly not meant to be a place for everyone.  If you don't want to do research before asking a question, you're not part of the target audience.

Comment: @Servy: Perfect example for my post, especially the part stating "ivory tower". Why exactly do we not _want_ those people? Why don't we invite ppl rather than chill them away **for-basically-ever**? The guy I am talking about would have been an awesome addition to our community, coming from an orthogonal background, having deep philosophical knowledge, tec-knowledge, etc., after learning the basic usage of Stack Overflow; everyone commits to errors at some point, even and especially you and myself, @Servy! But the mentioned guy has finished with us already, so thanks a lot.

Comment: @phresnel Because going out of your way to welcome low quality content, and to refuse to remove low quality content drives away experts.  People who want others to do their work for them love it when people do their work for them.  Subject experts looking to spend some time answering questions don't love it when they see nothing but questions people couldn't bother to put into Google.  Virtually all of SO's competition does what you suggest, and allows most everything.  SO decided to set a standard, so everyone came here.  The standards are the reason for its success.

Comment: @Servy: My opinion is explicitly not to do their homework, but to show them how they can find the solution. I am even open to removing answers to dupe or low quality questions. You missed my point entirely ...

Comment: @phresnel You'll find that the *vast* majority of the people asking those types of questions have *no* interest in actually *learning*.  They want an answer, generally code that they can copy/paste.  Nothing else.  Spending time trying to teach them something is time wasted, as they won't bother doing anything with that since it's not an answer they can copy/paste.  Beyond that, the community simply doesn't have enough energy to try to teach every single user that isn't willing to put any effort into trying to solve their own problem.  There are too many of them, and too few contributors.

Comment: How do you know that the vast majority does not just return months later, in a matured condition? There cannot exist statistics on that. If given the choices RTFM(/however)-Tag, I consider just staying with duping questions is more productive for US and THEM in the longer term. From own experience, duping in the majority of cases is almost the same effort as tagging. If users don't show progress, we can start thinking on sanctioning them.

Answer (score -4):

There's nothing wrong with **simple questions**.

The only thing that is "wrong" is that Q&A software (such as the SO commercial enterprise),

## *does not technically address the issue of duplicates*.

It's just that simple.  Everything else is pissing in the wind.

## *Q&A software does not technically address the issue of duplicates*.

It's staggeringly, childishly, risibly, bucolically, obvious that this is the next development in Q&A software.

There should be a "technological" solution to duplicates, or near-duplicates.

I picture something among the lines .. all dupes / near-dupes should just **stack up as a huge amount of text** ... comment-like ... which people can wade through.  Humans (see: psychological studies: humans) are staggeringly good at wading through large volumes of text, so there's no problem there.

Idiots, wait I mean to say users, with high!!!!! points!!!!! could be allowed to associate one Q to another.

{This would provide thrills! for anyone still stuck in the 1930s, trying to "generate! points! on SO!". (Because it's kool! to have High! Points!)

Since the busy-body-class on the Internet is bigger than a VEKA-class transport vessel, it would only take a couple days fro a commercial enterprise like SO to have its, uh, users make a huge amount of value for it, by aligning all.

None of this is going to happen, obviously, since SO is now a Western-democracy-like "USMO" (Ultra-Slow-Moving-Organisation).

Everything else on this page is complete crap.  Blether about how to socially manipulate newbie idiots, how to socially manipulate the high! point! class, etc., etc.

Answer (score -11):

I have rarely seen a blindingly-obvious-true-RTFM question here on SO. I think it is also a case of some people wanting to derive the pleasure of saying RTFM!

A seemingly foolish question if discussed and answered respectfully, can sometimes lead to great insight - and frequently benefits the person who answers with a stronger and deeper understanding.

In the history of Science and Technology, often the people who said RTFM were telling you to go and look at Established Truth. They were the Keepers of the Flame (the Manual), and were those who discouraged discussion and different 'foolish' perspectives from beginners - and missed the opportunity to discover the earth-shaking breakthroughs.

examples:

- Galileo and the Catholic church establishment,
- "Professor Goddard does not know the relation between action and 
  reaction and the need to have something better than a vacuum against 
  which to react.  He seems to lack the basic knowledge ladled out daily 
  in high schools.[**RTFM!**]" - 1921 New York Times editorial about Robert 
  Goddard's revolutionary rocket work.
- "If I want to stop a research program I can always do it by getting a few 
  experts to sit in on the subject, because they know right away that it 
  was a fool thing to try in the first place.[**RTFM!**]"   - Charles Kettering, GM

  quotes from    http://amasci.com/weird/skepquot.html

Comment: But there are 8,000 new questions every day on SO and many of them are this type of question. If there is a stronger and deeper understanding being developed from these, it's very hard to see.

Comment: @Pekka웃 If there is a stronger and deeper understanding, you will likely not see it. It is the people who interact with open minds, are the ones who will benefit.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I apologize for any misunderstanding - I am not implying that you have a closed mind

Comment: no offense taken!

Comment: You're not wrong here, but you're missing the point. The SO questions to which this would apply are not intriguing puzzles with opportunities for creative discovery; they're "how do i concatenate a string in xcode?" We're not talking about Science in this case -- we're talking about basic craftsmanship.

Comment: "They laughed at Einstein, they laughed at Galileo, but they also laughed at Bozo the Clown." - Carl Sagan.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I have rarely seen a blindingly obvious true RTFM question here on SO. I think it is also a case of some people wanting to derive the pleasure of saying RTFM!

Comment: Rare? No, common. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28100609

Answer (score -24):

No, because googling is itself a skill that beginners often don't have, and you can't really blame them.

It takes a while to learn it and have it really sink in. I've been through it, I know. You probably have too.

Comment: Downvote. The explicit mission statement is that SO is "for professional and enthusiast programmers". Nowhere in there does it say this site is here to teach beginners the absolute basics - like the fact that there's documentation about their language/framework/library available and they should read it if they have any problems. And while you don't have to "blame" or flame them for this, you also shouldn't support their incompetence by spoon-feeding them bits and pieces from the docs. Better teach them to help themselves by pointing out they should read the official documentation first.

Comment: @l4mpi I agree with you, but one problem I've been through is that some documentation is unreadable, such as certain man-pages. Though, that's not the issue with the questions we're talking about.

Comment: @keyser I'd say it's totally OK to ask a question about not understanding the documentation, as long as it's clear that OP looked at and tried to understand the docs. Something like "this and that is ambiguous or hard to understand in the docs, can someone explain it in detail" is a perfectly acceptable question as it shows OP is willing to learn and trying to understand the subject at hand.

Comment: @l4mpi Yup. I'd like to see us cultivate such a culture.

Comment: @l4mpi: What part of "enthusiast programmer" excludes beginners?

Comment: @Mehrdad I didn't say SO excludes beginners, but "enthusiast" IMO implies a desire to learn that includes searching for resources on their own. Now, if you say that some beginners are missing the skills to do so, that's too bad and they should be directed to resources that deal with learning these skills - but this is off-topic for SO, and should not be a reason for us to lower the quality standards we expect from questions. The help page and the downvote arrow explicitly state that we expect OP to do research; if OP is unable to do so this doesn't magically make his question acceptable.

Comment: I agree that Googling skill is not anyone has, and I can tolerate it if the search matter is quite hard in the first place. But given a mountainous amount of questions in SO, and some official references, if someone asks *FAQ*, I doubt he *can* use Google at all. Almost always if I google the title of a new (trivial) question, I get the solution on first page, and I just wish OP had already done that too. And that is not a basic skill in using Google? (This exempts some cases, like obscure reference from 3rd-party API)

Comment: In my early days, I can remember doing countless searches and not finding anything, then asking in frustration only to be told to go RTFM. If you don't know what keywords to use, you won't find what you're looking for. Generally, once someone pointed me to the resource, I figured things out from there. Also, I stopped to ask myself how my search terms could be refined and improved. I appreciated the patience of those who helped and still remember those who weren't patient. It's easy to forget we were all new once.

Comment: To further @jmort253's point, I've seen high-quality questions just asking for which terms to look for in documentation. Here's a good one from Music.SE: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/16304/midi-how-do-i-refer-to-and-search-for-software-that-will-play-audio-from-a-mi

Comment: Apologize if my previous comment looked harsh. Perhaps, just because I'm one of people who don't really like asking questions (even in real life) makes me tries to find the answer by myself, including how to use better keyword. In fact, I didn't wholly disagree with this answer (I leave it neutral; no upvote/downvote). I agree that the linked-question on Kevin's comment is a good one, though I'm not sure that kind of questions can survive in SO. If anyone finds similar questions in SO counterpart, please do comment to convince me.

Comment: @l4mpi: You reasoning is insentient. For my part, I once could code complete programs by scanning the books at my nearby library, yet lacked any websearch skills because the web was too new. Nowadays, this still may happen to anyone not gifted with enough money for internet access (or kids restricted by their parents), but (accidentally?) given the gift of an old computer with a compiler installed (e.g. by the uncle who brings a computer sorted out by his company).

Comment: @phresnel had to google insentient; I guess I'm a cold, heartless machine fueled by downvotes and closed questions :) First of all, someone without internet access certainly won't ask questions on SO. Second, as stated countless times already, SO is NOT the place to learn the absolute basics of programming. Third, I'm not saying we shouldn't help people like this, but I'd help them by pointing out better approaches to learning and researching than asking the n-th duplicate, no (visible) effort, unclear question on SO; and help everybody else by not having to deal with one more such question.

Comment: `"No, because Googling is itself a skill that beginners often don't have"` - Well, they should. If you don't have that skill, learning it is more urgent than asking for programming help. `"(...and you can't really blame them."` - Yes you can.

Comment: I can only believe that the above answer was made in jest.  Googling is a fundamental skill to both serious researchers and goof-off students who want to parrot an answer from the Internet rather than do their own work.  I doubt that anyone can advance much beyond the 4th grade these days without becoming at least passably good at it.

Comment: @HotLicks: It was a completely serious answer, but I'm sure you won't understand it if you haven't seen people who don't know how to Google for programming-related material.

Comment: We're not talking rocket-science compound searches here -- just take, eg, an exception message and paste it into the Google search line.  That sort of thing.  Anyone who doesn't know how to do that (or can't figure it out in 15 minutes) is (if you'll excuse the expression) an idiot.

Comment: @HotLicks: I understand perfectly well what you're saying and I'm telling you not every non-"idiot" can do what you're saying.

Comment: And not every non-"idiot" can program either.  I'll make exceptions for the art student who explains that he's out of his league but needs help on something, but anyone presenting himself as a "programmer" (or wannabe) should have basic skills for using Google, reading documentation, etc.

Comment: @HotLicks: I'm not sure why you're continuing to argue. I'm talking about non-"idiot" *beginner programmers* here. You're wrong and I have seen evidence with my own eyes, but I'm not going to drag people in front of you to prove you wrong. Don't believe me if you don't want to.

Comment: From the downvotes I suspect a lot of other people don't believe you either.

Comment: @HotLicks: I don't really care if people like to have illusions. There's a reason I haven't deleted the answer.

Comment: I *believe* you. I have no illusions, for I have seen it with my own eyes. I just don't know why we want to cater to these types of idiots. (I still disagree with the proposal, just for different reasons.)