# Close reason for questions where the OP should read a book first?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Asking about this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24086331/the-difference-with-pointers-inside-and-and-outside

[image]

Now the OP asks the difference between `Vector< IParticleOperation  *>  mParticleOps ;` and `Vector< Particle > *        mParticles ;`.

The problem in this question is that the OP obviously didn't read, or didn't understand the topic about templates and pointers in his C++ book (if they read one at all).

My first question is - should we really be answering those questions? And if they should be closed, what is the most appropriate reason? Can we use a custom off-topic reason like "Read a book first", for example?

Comment: This close reason does not exist anymore. Under the current incarnation of the system, downvote these questions (no research effort), and close them as duplicates if you can.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Did it really exist at one time?

Comment: Not in such a crude form, no. But [still it was removed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/257868/464709), because it was being used with that meaning.

Comment: @sashoalm There was once a "lack a minimal understanding of the topic" close reason specifically designed for questions in which the asker doesn't understand enough of the topic to be able to understand an answer given to them.  However it was not primarily used for that purpose, but rather abused to close questions in which the OP just didn't try hard to solve their problem.

Comment: Better duplicate: [Should we add RTFM to the list of off-topic close reasons?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253473)

Answer (score 5):

What you're saying here is that in order to actually answer the question in a manner understandable to the asker you'd need to pretty much write a whole book in order to explain the topic at a level that they would be able to understand, due to a lack of background knowledge on their part.

When you would need to write out a book just to answer a question, then that question is "Too Broad".

Comment: I think the question is more along the lines of "What should I do with overly simple questions that are answered by the documentation?" Sort of a "Is RTFM a valid close reason?"

Comment: Then the answer is no, @apaul. RTFM is not a valid close reason. It might be a valid reason to downvote, but it doesn't make the question unacceptable for Stack Overflow. The only time you'd vote to close is if the question is too broad to be reasonably answered. Like Servy's answer says.