# On what grounds should a question asking blindly for code be closed?

Tags: support, review-queues, close-reasons

So, whilst reviewing first posts I came across https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297180/woocommerce-order-details-overview and for the life of me, I can't seem to figure out what to do with it. I am pretty sure it should get closed, but I can't find any specific rule it's breaking. It is about programming and the 'problem' is clearly defined and not too broad or anything, but all the author did was grab the code form [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108549/woocommmerce-show-sku-in-cart-page) and ask 'us' to write the other code he wants. It's not truly too specific either, so yeah, at a loss.

Comment: A bad decision by SO was to remove the "minimal understanding" close reason. However, you can still use it with [this work-around](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253473/should-we-add-rtfm-to-the-list-of-off-topic-close-reasons/254829#254829).

Comment: Another example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24281516/i-need-a-perl-script-for-following-requirements Here the two often used reasons fit even worse. It is not really unclear what the asker is asking: The specifications are quite clear and they want code. And it neither really is too broad. With perl, there is a pretty easy and straightforward way to do that in a few lines. Of course different answerers might take slightly different routes but that is true with virtually every question in the Perl tag.

Comment: @DanielA.White: Read the answer for the first link you linked and then the question linked here. Though I agree the question is quite close, the answer is entirely unrelated. Regarding your second link, by those standards only the question should have been kept open.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's a cool trick available to people with full close vote privileges like yourself that is worth knowing about for questions like this one.

When closing a question as "off topic", you can actually enter a *custom* off-topic reason in a free-form textbox and vote to close on that basis. After you cast your vote, the system will automatically generate a comment on your behalf with your message.

You can see it in action if you visit the question under consideration—I used it with a smile on my face:

> This question appears to be off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Please [edit] your question to describe the problem you are having with the code in more detail and [include a *minimal* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

<sup>I used to use "not a code-debugging service" all the time, but that's now been addressed by the newly-added close reason explicitly for that purpose. (Note that when you enter this reason exactly as shown, the `[edit]` automatically turns into a smart link to the actual editing page for the post. Works for all comments.)</sup>

This comes in handy when none of the canned reasons are a perfect fit. Certainly, like Anonymous said, you could pick "unclear" or "too broad" and be done with it. No doubt there's a good argument to be made that the question is either or both of those things. The only problem is that they don't really give the asker enough information, should (s)he actually care to improve his/her question. The custom closure reason satiates my OCD *and* provides a concrete benefit.

…That is, if you're willing to invest the time to compose one for each low-quality question you come across. If you're not, try [this](https://stackapps.com/questions/4483/close-reason-editor-customize-your-off-topic-close-reasons).

Comment: That's a great Close Reason - not snarky, to the point and with a link to the relevant FAQ. Would you mind if I copy it and use it when I see a similar question?

Comment: **Your custom close reason is no longer visible**, as the question is deleted.  Perhaps edit it into your answer?

Comment: Yes, feel free to plagiarize away and/or adapt as desired. No attribution required. @tim

Comment: I thought I just read a few weeks ago that the "correct" procedure was to simply downvote? (no research effort, not useful) That said, +1 for your close reason - everything Tim said, plus it can't be misused in the way Lacks Minimal Understanding apparently was.

Answer (score 8):

Ignore the meaning of the message.  Focus on the delivery.  This question (if such a thing existed here) is **unclear**.

If we pare it down, then we arrive at this:

> added this nice code to display the SKU in cart:
>
> Want the same in order_details but have no clue how to modify.
>
> Kind regards

First, they got some code.  Cool story.  Now, they want the same in something called `order_details`, but they're unsure how to proceed.

Well, I'm not sure what they mean by "no clue how to modify".  Could it be that they don't have access to an editor/IDE?  Do they not have access to the web server it's hosted on?  Do they not understand PHP?

It's pretty unclear, but even if we were to reword it into something that was slightly more clear, it would still be considerably off-topic, since it's unclear as to what they were trying to do with `order_details`, or what it has to do with their code snippet.

If you're ever confused as to what to close it as, first strip away the message, and look at the delivery.  If the delivery is clear, but the question itself feels too all-encompassing (i.e. "How do I build a forum?"), close it as **Too Broad**.   If the delivery is unclear, then close it as **Unclear what you're asking**. (Hint:  a good indicator of this close type is also a lack of question marks.)

Answer (score 2):

I voted to close it as *unclear what you're asking*, but it could definitely also be closed as *too broad*.  *Unclear what you're asking* seems better because they don't even ever ask a question (especially not a specific question).  Also, a downvote would be appropriate because it is unclear where they ran into a problem.

If the question were to ask an actual question, too broad would be appropriate because their question would not be at all specific enough since there could possibly be a myriad of different answers depending on expertise and personal preference.

Comment: "Unclear what you're asking" is best. It is hardly "too broad", since it does present a specific task for us to complete. The issue is that there is no question. Also consider a custom off-topic reason; see my answer.

Comment: Still, if a custom close reason were used for every low quality question, it would cause issues in the close votes queue because everything would be off-topic.  Also, the listed close reasons show up in a clearer way to the person asking the question.  The custom one just says it needs to fit the help center and the poster needs to sift through possibly tons of comments to find the right one that explains why their question was closed.  At that point, it may be better to use a listed close reason and leave a comment explaining it in more detail.